# Chrome ignores 302 HTTPS to HTTP redirect of resource and causes CERT error

Tags: google-chrome, https

I have a page served via HTTPS. All content is public and no sensitive data is on this page. I also have resources (audio mp3) on a google cloud bucket which has no HTTPS support and is a subdomain (DNS C-NAME entry only), but is reachable via HTTPS but returns a Google certificate if accessed by https. Until now I had my server respond with a 302 redirect to my subdomain downgrading static mp3-resources from HTTPS to HTTP and it worked. See this request:

**Request:**

```
Request URL: https://x.com/q/ics/edit/r.6c19e2d99e220f648b3c1799ed05dc99.mp3
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: 172.217.19.115:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Response:**

```
content-length: 259
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 24 Jun 2020 05:42:46 GMT
location: http://subdomain.x.com/ics/_resources/r.6c19e2d99e220f648b3c1799ed05dc99.mp3
server: Google Frontend
status: 302
x-cloud-trace-context: 3086726898e017b2b99858fcea43c5e0
```

But suddenly Chrome started ignoring **location: http:** and instead resolves the HTTPS version, which causes ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID and this fails the download.

I know this can be resolved by using a load-balancer, but that would almost double our hosting costs (maintenance/setup/learning costs not included!) and we really do not need a load balancer with AppEngine classic.

The problem occurred a few weeks ago the first time, but went away within a day, but is persistent now!

**Does anyone know why Chrome is interpreting the redirect this way? Is this required by any specification?**

Update: The only solution I found so far is to downgrade the whole page with a redirect from HTTPS to HTTP. That is really a sad solution.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior.  Very obnoxious that it's ignoring a deliberate protocol change by the server.  I too am doing it for cost reasons.  I'm streaming public audio, with nothing private about it.  I suppose cookies might accidentally be sent revealing secret info, but with the secure flag set properly on cookies, that shouldn't be a problem.  What is the rationale?

Comment: Not surprisingly, Chrome on Android is now doing the same.